# Helm Chart loads default Laravel instead of real site

Tags: docker, kubernetes, helm

I have set up my project to use this package for Kubernetes/Helm on Laravel application:
https://github.com/richdynamix/arc

When I run

```
docker-compose up
```

I get the real project I have been working on, but when I install Helm at tools/helm-chart folder using this command:

```
helm install .
```

I get the default laravel startup page, not the real project I have been working on.

Steps I have made:

1. Test with docker-compose up
2. Push to private docker repo using

   docker push myusername/reponame:latest
3. Setup helm chart details and docker user/pass at tools/helm-chart/values.yaml
4. Run

   helm install .
5. Visit deployed website to see its not working properly.

I have tested this on Google Cloud and locally. Same result.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not specific to `helm install`.

The problem is in **nginx** running in the front of Laravel app, making a mess. So if you were changing `server.php` for your project to, let's say, run `index.html` instead of `index.php`

```
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.html';
```

and run local server

```
    sukhoversha@master:~/suh$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

this will work, because traffic hits server.php directly.

However, when you run your project with `docker-compose up` (even without helm), all traffic goes to nginx first, which has `nginx.conf`with following line:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

And if you check that location, you'll fine this config: `default-20-rewriteapp.conf`

```
location @rewriteapp {

    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;

}
```

So to fix, you can either edit **index.php**  or edit **nginx configuration**

Hope this will help.